# Linked List not saving reference to next node

Tags: c, linked-list

I'm sure it's something obvious... but I've been at it for ages now and just can't spot the error of my ways, so hopefully some fresh eyes will nail it.

```
BOOLEAN init()
{
    struct list *foodList = (struct list*)malloc(sizeof(struct list));

    struct node *head = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    head->data = NULL;
    head->next = NULL;

    foodList->head = head;


    if (NULL == foodList) {
        printf("List creation failed");
        return FALSE;
    }


    return TRUE;
}


void add_node(struct list *foods, struct food * newFood) {


    struct node *curr = foods->head;

    while (curr->next != NULL) {
        curr = curr->next;
    }

    curr->next = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    curr->next->data = newFood;
     printf("%p\n", curr);
    curr->next->next = NULL;


    }
```

List is just a typical list struct, as is node.

What's happening is each node is getting created successfully (their addresses being 0x7fd1dac03ab0,
0x7fd1dac03ac0, etc.), but the node->next is returning 0x7fd1dac03960 on *every* node. Like I said, I'm sure I'm doing something painfully obvious here... But any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just use one of the many existing linked list implementations.

Comment: Where is `foods` defined in `init()` function, you have used it here: `if (NULL == foods)`

Comment: [Don't cast the result of `malloc`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc). Also, you should check whether `foodList` is `NULL` *before* dereferencing it.

Comment: Consider switching to a node-based list implementation, without a distinct `head`. Just represent the entire list as a pointer to the first node. And seriously consider how you expect the head to ever change when calling `add_node()`.

Comment: `init()` : it's work to only memory leak. and `if (NULL == foodList) {` : Too late.